# Monitors in operating systems

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

"Monitors are language specific constructs" -  What does this mean? Does this mean they are compiler/programming language dependent? If so,they can't be implemented in C right?
I was asked to implement a monitor in C.Initially though of a monitor struct ..but as it cannot hold functions,it is of no use.Any ideas someone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That quote sounds completely wrong without context. Of course you can implement one in C, just as you can do OOP and virtual functions in C. It's just the style and conventions that are different.

Comment: The abstraction that c provides is not powerful enough for monitor as a separate data structure isn't it?

Comment: I 'm not sure what "separate data structure" means. C does not have classes, so you emulate them with structs and free functions.

Comment: Exactly,i misquoted what i wanted to mean...C cannot support monitors the way i thought about them - using monitor as a struct can only result in using the condition variables and no methods...

Comment: @404: if you want to fake up the syntax of a method call in C, then you can give your struct function pointers as data members. You do have to explicitly pass `this`, though. You can implement varieties of polymorphism by putting different functions in the slots, or you can get more elaborate and implement vtables etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Some languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29#History) have built-in support for the synchronization primitive known as the monitor. Others don't. C does not. It may be implemented in C, but its implementation will ultimately depend on the CPU and/or the OS.

Comment: It would certainly be possible in languages like java..But doing it in C confuses me...i need to read about virtual function implementation...as Jon had mentioned...only then will i get an idea of how to implement this in c

Comment: If it helps, it has been shown that monitors, semaphores and condition variables are equivalent and can be constructed from one another.

Comment: This seems a very reasonable thing to assume if you are to build a monitor in c...ill just use a condition variable as a semaphore and another mutex to ensure only 1 process enters the "function" which controls entry into monitor

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: that said, it is *very difficult* to construct condition variables from semaphores, especially if the associated mutex is to have timedwait and trylock. The implementation of a Java-style monitor using one mutex and one condition variable is pretty obvious though.

Answer (score 1):

The monitors can be implemented in C language.
Here is an example, you can try this.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h> 

struct monitor_DataType {
  sem_t OKtoRead;
  sem_t OKtoWrite;
  int readerCount; 
  int isBusyWriting;
  int readRequested; 
};

struct monitor_DataType monitor_data; 

void monitor_StartWrite() {
    if(monitor_data.isBusyWriting || monitor_data.readerCount != 0){
sem_wait(&(monitor_data.OKtoWrite));
}
  monitor_data.isBusyWriting++;    
}

void monitor_EndWrite() {
   monitor_data.isBusyWriting--;
   if(monitor_data.readRequested){
      sem_post(&(monitor_data.OKtoRead));
   } else {
     sem_post(&(monitor_data.OKtoWrite));
   }
   }

// Function that will block until read can start

void monitor_StartRead() {
    if(monitor_data.isBusyWriting){ 
       monitor_data.readRequested++;
       sem_wait(&(monitor_data.OKtoRead));
       monitor_data.readRequested--;
       }
    monitor_data.readerCount++;
    sem_post(&(monitor_data.OKtoRead));
} 

// Function to signal reading is complete
void monitor_EndRead() {
    monitor_data.readerCount--;
    if(monitor_data.readerCount == 0){
    sem_post(&(monitor_data.OKtoWrite));
    }
}

// intialize the monitor
int monitor_Initialized(){  
int returnValue = 1;
 
// Initialize the structure
monitor_data.readerCount = 0;
monitor_data.isBusyWriting = 0;
monitor_data.readRequested = 0;

// initialize the semaphores
if(sem_init(&(monitor_data.OKtoWrite), 0, 1) == 0 && 
   sem_init(&(monitor_data.OKtoRead), 0, 1) == 0){
    returnValue = 0;
} else {
  printf("Unable to initialize semaphores\n");
}
 
return returnValue;
}

// Destroys the semphores.
void monitor_Destroy(){
  sem_destroy(&(monitor_data.OKtoWrite));
  sem_destroy(&(monitor_data.OKtoRead));
}
 
int main() {
if(monitor_Initialized() == 0){
 printf("Initialized\n");
 
 monitor_StartWrite();
 printf("Writing stuffs...\n");
 monitor_EndWrite();
 monitor_StartRead();
 printf("Reading stuffs...\n");
 monitor_EndRead();
monitor_Destroy();
}
 return 0;
}
```